# How to get images after upload in Spring controller without reload application?

Tags: spring-mvc, image-uploading

In my Spring Controller I wrote method that return images on JSP page from resources folder. But if I change resource (or) add new my InputStream is null. When I reload app it works again.

> What can I do to get images without reloading application?

my method in controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{authorUsername}/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public byte[] testphoto(HttpServletRequest request,
                            @PathVariable("authorUsername") String authorUsername,
                            @PathVariable("title") String title) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/" + title + "/0.jpg");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

on JSP page:

```
<img src="/image/${advert.authorUsername}/${advert.title}/">
```

**EDITED:**

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{authorUsername}/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public void testphoto(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                         @PathVariable("authorUsername") String authorUsername,
                                         @PathVariable("title") String title) throws IOException {

        InputStream instream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/" + title + "/0.jpg");
        byte[] bytes =  IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);
        int contentLength = IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentLength(contentLength);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + "0.jpg" + "\"");
    }
```

**EDITED 2:**

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{authorUsername}/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public void testphoto(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                     @PathVariable("authorUsername") String authorUsername,
                                     @PathVariable("title") String title) throws IOException {

    String contextPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    String directory = contextPath.substring(0,contextPath.length() - 18) + "/target/YaPokupay/src/main/webapp/resources/uploadImages/" + authorUsername + "/" + title + "/0.jpg";

    File file = new File(directory);
    String filePath = file.getPath(); // D:\Works\YaPokupay\target\YaPokupay\src\main\webapp\resources\uploadImages\zeus192\Картинка\0.jpg
    InputStream instream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);

    byte[] bytes =  IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);
    int contentLength = IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), response.getOutputStream());
    response.setContentLength(contentLength);

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + "0.jpg" + "\"");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me for mutiple request of same resource.My resource is at (../ProjectName/src/main/webapp/resources/images/logos)

```
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sampleJavaOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sampleJavaOperation(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        InputStream instream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/logos/wavemaker_62x62.png");
        byte[] bytes =  IOUtils.toByteArray(instream);
        int contentLength = IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), response.getOutputStream());
        response.setContentLength(contentLength);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + "0.png" + "\"");
    }
```

Comment: What means _@WMAccessVisibility(value = AccessSpecifier.APP_ONLY)_ and _@ApiOperation(value = "")_?

Comment: sry,those are my own annotations.updated code and they will not impact this service.

Comment: This code work in the same way: images loaded from target folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to download file from Spring controller.Adding httpServletResponse as parameter and setting your file stream to response output stream.

```
   @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{authorUsername}/{title}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public void testphoto(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,
                            @PathVariable("authorUsername") String authorUsername,
                            @PathVariable("title") String title) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/" + title + "/0.jpg");
        Byte[] bytes =  IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        int contentLength = IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), response.getOutputStream());
        httpServletResponse.setContentLength(contentLength);
    }
```

If you want to render images in browser,then add a header "Content-Disposition" as inline else attachment, which will download file to your local machine.

```
if(inline){  // if you want to attachment to be inline
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
}else{
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
}
```

Comment: I need to create new response? Or response and httpServletResponse is the same things?

Comment: Where I need to add "Content-Disposition"?

Comment: Use same HttpServletResponse param which is declared in the parameters to set Content-Disposition header.Updated code with http servlet response.

Comment: So, my method must loks like that: edited in question? But it works in the same way.

Comment: I think every time you are using same stream,hence from second request stream is becoming empty because it is already processed.Just check with this code servletContext.getResource("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/" + title + "/0.jpg").openStream()  , if it doesnt work create your own stream as new FileInputStream(new File(servletContext.getResource("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/" + title + "/0.jpg").getPath()))

Comment: I noticed, that InputStream instream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/uploadImages/zeus192/") get files from target folder, but it have to from project folder. It's obviously that it will not be changes. How can I change destination/folder?

Comment: I get NullPointerException in both cases with stream

Comment: servletContext.getResourceAsStream(..) will point to servletContext that is static files which are sibling to WEB-INF folder.If you want to load any classpath resources(Which are there inside WEB-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib) you can use this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(..)

Comment: I change my method(EDITED 2) but InputStream = null

Comment: It seems your resource is at webapp "src\main\webapp\resources\uploadImages\zeus192\Картинка\0.jpg",then it is not in class path,so class loader approach will not work.To get static resources you should use servletContext.getResourceAsStream("...");

Comment: I change **InputStream instream2 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);** on **InputStream instream2 = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(filePath);** but it still null.

Comment: it seems you have an absolute path so why not `InputStream instream = Files.newInputStream(filePath);`

Comment: I want to store files(images) uploaded by user in app folder. Target not good for it because when I redeploy project (for example on heroku) I lose all files. Which one is better and how can I get files from there?

Comment: In this case  uploaded files should persist in server file system or database or cloud(dropbox,remote repos,git,...).If you want to persist in server file system,then you should add system property to application server about path to upload and provide permission to upload directory.

Comment: Ok, Is there some easy free way to upload files on cloud?